# Vue Composition Api - watch property passed to external composition function

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vue-composition-api

I want to watch props passed to a composition function from setup:

```
async setup(props) {
  const { data } = await useOperation(query, props.isEdit);
}
```

and each time the value of isEdit changes, I want to do something in the watch:

```
export const useOperation = async (query, isEdit) => {
  const reload = ref(isEdit)
  watch(
    () => reload.value,
    (result) => {
      console.log(result)
    }
  )
  const { data } = await fetch(query)

  return {
    data
  }
}
```

When `props.isEdit` changes, the watch is not triggered. How do I make this work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should watch the props change directly in `setup`:

```
async setup(props) {
  const { data } = await useOperation(query, props.isEdit);

  watch(
    () => props.isEdit,
    (result) => {
      console.log(result)
    }
  )
}
```

By running:

```
watch(
  () => reload.value,
  (result) => {
    console.log(result)
  }
)
```

You are watching the `reload` variable instead of `props.isEdit`, and since `useOperation` is only run once during `setup`, and `reload` is not exposed anywhere, its value will never be changed.

---

Or if you do want to watch in `useOperation`, make sure you pass in the `props` as parameter,  and `watch` for `props.isEdit`:

```
export const useOperation = async (query, props) => {
  watch(
    () => props.isEdit,
    (result) => {
      console.log(result)
    }
  )
...
```